# AngularJS - Binding the model to inputs that were not created with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, user-interface

I have the following ui scenario: 
Need to create a ui with three inputs to allow the user to enter his/her favorite movies. Those inputs will be always three except that they were populated previously, or except that the user uploaded three movies and he/she is coming back to see the list.

So:
Case 1: The user doesn't have any data stored. So there should be three inputs, not generated with hg-repeat, but bounded to the model.

Case 2: The user has less than two (out three) movies loaded. Two inputs can be generated with hg-repeat, but the last one it must be shown.

Case 3: The user has three inputs filled, the ui must generate a four -empty- blank input to allow the user to continue adding his/her favorite movies.

Which is the best approach with angular to achieve this?

Thanks so much in advance,

Guillermo

Comment: Can you show what have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi Vinod, I've tried something similar to what Sebastien explained, but I was not able to bind the data to the model. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In each case, you should use a ng-repeat. And I would do something like this :

1. create an object to store the value

`movies={movie1:undefined, movie2:undefined, movie3undefined}`

1. Pre-fill this object with user loaded movies if any
2. create your ng-repeat

`<li ng-repeat='movie in movies'>` with you input binded to movies : `<input ng-model='movies[movie]'>`

You can also create a last li item with a `ng-if` testing if the 3 values are filled and then adding a fourth input.

Comment: Thanks so much Sebastien! Will try your solution. Regards!